# Setting up a cvsrepository with username and passwd

Tags: cvs

I have been trying to set up the cvs repository but wasn't able to do it. I would give you the description of the steps that i have followed

i have got cvs and cvsd installed.
i have the following code in xinetd.d

```
service cvspserver
{
     port = 2401
     socket_type = stream
     protocol = tcp
     user = root
     wait = no
     type = UNLISTED
     server = /usr/bin/cvs
     env = HOME=/home/cvs/cvsroot
     server_args = -f --allow-root /home/ks/cvs/cvsroot pserver
     disable = no
}
```

i have set SystemAuth=no so that it doesn't look into system passwords

i have added user and groups with apporpriate permissions
and i have created a passwd file inside the CVSROOT
and used mkpasswd to encrypt the password

i have got the following result when i have checked to see if the server is up:
`netstat -tap | grep cvs` :

```
tcp        0      0 *:cvspserver            *:*                   LISTEN      1016/cvsd       
tcp        0      0 localhost:cvspserver    localhost:42965         TIME_WAIT   -
```

which shows that server is on and running
when i try with
`export CVSROOT=:pserver:username1@localhost:/home/cvs/cvsroot` &&`cvs login`

i am not able to login into the server, it always gives me an error
cvs [login aborted]: unrecognized auth response from localhost: cvs [pserver aborted]: /home/cvs/cvsroot: no such repository

i have searched throughout  the internet and have gone through many tutorials.
kindly tell me if i have to check something else. where i have gone wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I too worked around /etc/cvs/xinetd.d/cvs but no success you have to work around **Step-5 and 6**

Here are steps to setup a proper CVS repository

**1.** Verify CVS, whether installed or not

```
  $su - root 


    $cvs -v
    Concurrent Versions System (CVS) 1.11.22 (client/server)
    Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    ...
```

.  if you don’t have CVS installed on your system, install it from your Linux distribution repository. For example, on redhat based system, install the RPM as shown below.

```
  $rpm -ivh cvs-1.11.22-5.el5.i386.rpm
```

**2.** Create CVS User and Groups

```
  $useradd cvs
  $passwd cvs
   .. give password cvs for example
```

If you want only **developers** to access the CVS repository, create a developers group as shown below.

```
    $groupadd **developers**
```

**3.** Create CVS Repository Directory

```
     $mkdir /home/cvs/myrepo
```

Now As root user-->

 **a.** if want to restrict directory to only **developers** group, if not skipp

```
 $chgroup developers /home/cvs/myrepo
```

**b.** Now give full privileged group

$chmod g+srwx /home/cvs/myrep

**4.** Now Initialize the standalone directory to make repository directory

```
  $su - cvs
  $su /home/cvs/myrepo init
```

**5.** Here you have to work around global xinetd.d service configuration file /etc/xinetd.conf 
      For 
 [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Reference_Guide/s2-tcpwrappers-xinetd-config-files.html) and
 
 [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/rhel-rg-en-4/s1-tcpwrappers-xinetd-config.html)

Inside /etc/configure following service
and append your CVS rep. directory to

```
 server_arg = --allow-root=/home/cvs/myrepo -f pserver 


service cvspserver
{
        Port = 2401
                socket_type = stream
                protocol = tcp
                wait = no
                user = root
                server = /usr/bin/cvs
                server_args = --allow-root=/home/cvs/myrepo  --allow-root=/home/cvs/myrepotwo -f pserver
                env = HOME=/home/cvs/repository
                log = /var/log/cvslog
}

#last line of xinetd.conf should be
includedir /etc/xinetd.d
```

**6.** Now  reload the xinetd.conf file followed by xinetd.d service restart

```
  # /etc/rc.d/init.d/xinetd reload
  # service xinetd restart
```

**7.** Set following is ~/.bash_profile Ensure no trailing space in line

```
 export CVSROOT=:pserver:[cvs or user from group]@[hostname or ip address]:/home/cvs/mtoirepo
```

and execute the bash_profile

```
 #. ~/.bash_profile
```

**8.** Login from **cvs** user

```
    #cvs login
    Logging in to :pserver:m2i@[host IP]:2401/home/cvs/mtoirepo
    CVS password:
```

**9.** Set **CVS repo** for new user or existing user

```
     #useradd developers myuser
or
     #usermod -G developers myuser
```

and follow the **setp-7** , Now CVS is ready from that client user.